# Nginx " Cannot GET /api " Reverse Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-linux-2

My problem:

I need to do a reverse proxy with Nginx in AWS  Linux 2 (Free), and the nginx doesn´t stop throwing me  Cannot GET /api ...
Code:

```
    server {
        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

And nothing the only way this works is with

```
    server {
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

But don't works the /api/something

Here my Nginx.conf

```
   user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }
```

some commands used are:

```
+sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp –-dport 80 -m state –state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
+sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 -y
```

Comment: Try `location /api/ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/; }`.

Comment: You have made me one of the happiest people in the world = _) THANKS !! = _)